What is this actor's name in Inglourious Basterds?
No matter how much I research, I can not find this actor's name?
The SS officer who comes and interrogates the Americans,
Seen here at 0:02 in the below video;




Uh...try harder.

LOL, "This appears to be off-topic for the site". So why is there an "Identify-this-actor" tag? @NapoleonWilson, I would retort, but I would most likely get banned from this site as well.

Check the specific reason please. We're not replicating IMDb here.

This appears to be August Diehl who played the role of that officer whose name is Major Dieter Hellstrom.


August Diehl (born 4 January 1976) is a German actor, primarily known to international audiences for playing SS-Sturmbannführer Dieter Hellstrom in Inglourious Basterds

(Image Courtesy: Wikipedia)
From Wikia:

One of the German soldiers present strikes up a conversation with Hicox and notices that his accent is "odd". An SS officer, Major Dieter Hellstrom, who is in the tavern as well also notices that odd accent. When Hicox gives the wrong three fingered order for whiskies (without using his thumb, a traditional German gesture), the SS officer realizes their deception.


Nice, will accept when time permits.

Wow, I bet that guy is pretty much restricted to SS officer/serial killer/dying artist roles...
